# Why isn't Javascript retrieving values of PHP variables?

Tags: javascript, php

When I run this code, the alerts fail to display the values and instead an empty alert box pops up.

```
<?php
$x = 20;
$y = "Hello World!";

$list = array();
$list[0] = "January";
$list[1] = "February";
$list[2] = "March";
$list[3] = "April";
$list[4] = "May";
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
alert("JS code executed");
alert(<?php  $x  ;?>);
alert(<?php echo $list[3];?>);
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the generated JS source.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks This depends on the origin of `$x` or `$list`, if it's safe or not, so you can not say that a vulnerability really exists...

Answer (score 1):

First, you aren't echoing `$x`.

Second, you need to quote the string for JavaScript, so:

```
alert("<?php echo $list[3]; ?>");
```

would work.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: I'm showing OP why their alert isn't working. The rest is up to them, not me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your Browser's Development tools to see what is happening with you javascript.

If you look at Console, you will see something like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: April is not defined
```

This is because you forgot putting Quotes on your script, also you forgot to echo the $x. The right code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("JS code executed");
alert("<?php echo $x  ;?>");
alert("<?php echo $list[3];?>");
</script>
```

@Slaks said that this code have an XSS vulnerability, but this depends on if the origin of your `$x` and `$list` variable is safe or not.